# Copying Specific Cell Content From One WorkSheet To Another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where I want specific Cell content replicated into another sheet ie:
Meeting Agenda "E7" to Meeting Record col G next available Row
Meeting Agenda "E9" to Meeting Record col B next available Row
Meeting Agenda "C10" to Meeting Record col C next available Row
Meeting Agenda "B14, B15, B16, B17,B 18" to Meeting Record col F next available Row

I have managed to move the data using this type of code

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")
```

however, I can't get it into next row

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & rows.count).end(xlup).offset(1)`

Comment: @SJR Sounds more like an answer, rather than a comment :)

Comment: Hi @SJR, that works fine on one line but I need to copy the content of 4 different cell ranges to 4 different cols. Currently, if I run as is, I receive a run-time error '1004' Copy method of Range class failed.

Comment: Sheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("e7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Meeting Record").Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Sheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("e9").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Meeting Record").Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Sheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("c10").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Meeting Record").Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Comment: Sheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("b14:b18").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Meeting Record").Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Sheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("e7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Meeting Record").Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Comment: Also... Cells B13:B18, I wanted all in one cell (eg Bob, Bill, Sue, etc)

Comment: OK, so I have this working: Worksheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("E7").Copy
Worksheets("Meeting Record").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("E9").Copy
Worksheets("Meeting Record").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("C10").Copy
Worksheets("Meeting Record").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: However, in my last line: Worksheets("Meeting Agenda").Range("B14").Copy
Worksheets("Meeting Record").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues I want to be able to copy the content of 5 cells into one in col F, each record separated by a comma

Comment: Resolved it myself.